# How to optimize SQL settings for fully cached wordpress site

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, caching

I have a site with mysql 5.5, I have installed wordpress and a cache plugin that generates html pages. The site has about 50k visitors per day, and sometimes my site "crashes" (backend only or sometimes also frontend) so I need to stop sql server, and reboot it. (this crashes can be 1 in months or more than 1 in a week, they happen randomly)
(when I reboot the sql server, the site still fully working because of the html cache + "cloudflare always on") but I want to avoid this crashes. This is my sql config (ovh)
ps: my site dont have WP users, only admins, so cache is always on for every visitor

```
[mysqld]

tmp_table_size=400M
query_cache_size=1M

skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 12M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_cache = 4
table_open_cache = 96
sort_buffer_size = 64K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 256K
net_buffer_length = 2K
thread_stack = 128K
thread_cache_size = 4


max_heap_table_size = 600M
max_binlog_cache_size = 1M
max_join_size = 1M
max_seeks_for_key = 2M
max_write_lock_count = 512K
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 1M



########################
##Configuration Innodb##
##Uncomment the next line to disable Innodb

skip-innodb
default-storage-engine=myisam

innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M

innodb_log_file_size            = 10M
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 4M

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
```

How I can optimize this configuration?

Or maybe I need to upgrade my offer?
actually I have this: https://www.ovh.co.uk/web-hosting/performance-web-hosting.xml web performance 1 + private sql with 128mb ram + cloudflare cdn/cache

also, the plugin used for cache is this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-fastest-cache/faq/ and I run "optimize/repair" query very often

Comment: Do you know WHY MySQL server is crashing?

Comment: no, maybe for too many queries or for poor server cpu/ram. When I first installed WP, that server was going really bad, even with 10k visits per day, but with that settings I wrote above, it was going good until some month ago, when it started crashing randomly.

Comment: Its rather more difficult fixing an error when you dont know what the error is. Have you looked through the logs on the server? Apache and PHP and MYSQL

Comment: this are the most common errors  `FastCGI: comm with server "/homez.444/example/www/file.php" aborted: idle timeout (300 sec)
 [error] [client 000] [host www.example.org] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/homez.444/example/www/file.php"
 [error] [client 000] [host www.example.org] FastCGI: An error happend on Fastcgi processing, fallback to CGI
 [error] [client 000] [host www.example.org] FastCGI: comm with server "/homez.444/example/www/file1.php" aborted: idle timeout (300 sec), referer: http://www.example.org/article/`

Comment: but, i use this setting on my host `app.engine=php
app.engine.version=5.6
http.firewall=none
environment=production
container.image=legacy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should increase the log file size to > 2BG

I config for a Magento site with > 20k products and 3k users/days with values my.cnf bellow:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G
innodb_change_buffering=all
innodb_log_buffer_size=16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=20M
innodb_log_file_size = 1536M
innodb_autoextend_increment=512 

thread_concurrency = 3 
thread_cache_size = 32 
table_cache = 1024 
query_cache_size = 512M 
query_cache_limit = 512M 
join_buffer_size = 256M 
tmp_table_size = 512M 
key_buffer = 256M 
max_heap_table_size = 512M 
read_buffer_size = 512M 
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512M 
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 128M
```

The important values are

```
innodb_log_file_size
innodb_buffer_pool_size
```

Hope that make sense.

Comment: can you tell me the sql version you are using and the dedicated ram/cpu to sql server?  The config you posted seems very good for big sites, but I think it request a good sql server with a lot of ram/cpu, in that case i need to do some tests and upgrade my sql server

Comment: Hi Eazy, that sever has 16GB RAM and 8 core CPU. the innodb_log_file_size is not depend on RAM, you can increase that. I used mysql 5.5 for that server.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, now i'll do some tests with that cfg

Answer (score 0):

At 50k visitors a day, you are receiving `0.5787037037` visitors a second. If that's the case, I suggest either upgrading your server, to a SQL database that has more than just 128MB of RAM. If that's not an option, caching is your last resort.

Note though, no matter how hard you push caching, if your server is weak or poor to begin with, caching is still very limited.

Comment: I know that this server is "cheap" and I shoud buy better server, but when I first installed WP, that server was going really bad, even with 10k visits per day, but with that settings I wrote above, it was going good until some month ago, so maybe with better settings i can improve it to max

Comment: I think your settings are quite good, based on the server's performance. Regardless of that, if you are serving more or less static content, it's how the pages are cached that's going to affect your performance more.

If you really want to try and improve your server to the best, you can try an online configuration tool such as [Percona Tools](https://tools.percona.com/sign-in) under `Configuration Wizard`